# mini itx motherboard that supports triple monitor onboard?

Tags: mini-itx, multiple-monitors

HI,

I am trying to find a mini itx montherboard that supports onboard triple monitor. I tried to search on newegg and amazon, but no luck.

Comment: Shopping advice is Off Topic on Super User. [Why it is so.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't find such a thing. Almost all onboard graphics cards, especially on consumer motherboards, only allow 2 displays even if they have the physical connections for more. Your best chance here is a graphics card, and if you're trying to stuff it in a tiny cases, chances are that's not going to happen.

There are devices that can "split" a VGA signal such that two monitors appear to be one larger monitor, which gives you a better chance, but generally quality is poor, and resolution is limited. I'd say your best hope is a USB VGA dongle, but if you're doing anything 3d, or particularly high resolution, that won't help.

Also, not a shopping guide, yadda yadda.

Comment: Aren't there half-height graphics cards that should fit?

Comment: Depending on how small the case, perhaps. In a lot of the motherboards I've encountered, however, the internal graphics card is disabled when an aboveboard graphic card is inserted. In the Mini-ITX form factor, a motherboard that can handle two graphics cards seems... unlikely. Thus, simply having *one* half-height card doesn't answer the problem at hand.